# Biztalk schema deployed as one way service, how?

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a Biztalk 2009 project with a receive location using a SOAP adapter. Now it uses a request-response schema and I want to refactoring it in a asynchronous design, by only using the request schema (a one way scenario).

If I want to use the Biztalk Web Services Publishing Wizard, but I must use a response schema to let the wizard go to finish the job.

Is it - in Biztalk - required to always have a response type for every SOAP call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use one-way services with the SOAP-adapter in BizTalk (WCF-receive and send are a bit different however). All you need to do is to remove the two default methods you'll get in the wizard, add a new one as one-way and set it to the schema you'd like to use. Done.

Comment: Riri, that was also my idea ;-) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service that does not send an explicit response using the BizTalk WCF Publishing wizard (by adding a new, one-way service to the service when "creating WCF service from schemas"), but note that you aren't really creating an asynchronous WCF service.

Specifically, the WCF isOneWay flag is NOT set to "true", but rather, you are creating a WCF service that simply returns void.  This may not be an issue for your design, but good to be aware of (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226362(BTS.70).aspx).